# How to use assets while building Craft CMS plugins?

Tags: plugin-development, templating, craft3, php

I am trying to build a basic plugin, when installed has a single nav bar item, and of course a twig template which shows up on clicking on that navbar item.

I have used the basic template to extend to make my page:

```
{% extends "_layouts/cp" %}
{% set title = "Page Title"|t('plugin-handle') %}

{% block content %}
    <p>Page content goes here</p>
{% endblock %}
```

The resulting page for the plugin looks like shown in the screenshot attached below:

[image: Screenshot of basic template]

Now I am trying to add content in the content section, but I am not sure how to add my assets

`<img src="/resources/img/poptinlogo.png"/>`

This won't work, and I am guessing I need to get the paths using some variable in the twig templating system, but I am not sure how. And the documentation is not clear on this part, or maybe I don't know where to look right away.

How to include my assets on the page, like images, js and css files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register asset bundles in your plugin, see the Craft docs -> https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/asset-bundles.html